# Can't find header for TTURLJSONResponse

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, three20

I've tried to import the TTURLJSONResponse with #import , added the project to my project and added the library to the project dependencies. Now I've got an error that XCode can't find the header file. I can import "normal" Three20 without error. I can now build my project without error but in the editor it says that it can't find the header file. But it build without error.

Comment: Can you post the exact message Xcode gives you?

Comment: File not found... I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I solved it by creating a new project and make all settings again. Now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Under your project Build, you need to set where xcode is gonna look for the headers, something like
**Header Search Path** :

```
 "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../yourDirectory"
 "$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../yourDirectory"
```

and the Linker flags

**Other Linker Flags** : -ObjC -all_load

one other thing, don't forget to check the targets for each framework you wanna add

Comment: did you add both Framework Search Path and Header Search Path? You will need both

Comment: did you set "Other Linker Flags"?

Comment: I already answered my question. I just created a new project and did the settings again.

Answer (score 0):

the three20 JSON extension , including `TTURLJSONResponse` is a separated subproject, which isn't included in the standard three20 project. this means you will have to include the extension along with the standard three20 project.

There's a working example of it in the samples/TTTwitter project. This twitter example uses the three20 json extension to read json response from twitter. You can open the project and expand the Dependancies folder in that project.

To add the JSON Three20 Extension to your project, it should be enough to drag the `src/extThree20JSON/extThree20JSON.xcodeproj` into your project